# How protective should I be of my Facebook AppId?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It seems people are usually protective with the AppId, but it can be viewed by doing view-source on a page, no?

What are the security dangers if the appId gets into the wrong hands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Appid is public information.  The secret key should remain private.

Comment: and how can I keep it (secret) private if I am developing a native iOS/Android app? 
I read about storing it in a server, but if someone download the app and decode the app then it will be possible to get it just performing the same call. No?